# Is there a specific name for the function $f(x)=\frac{1}{c+e^{-x}}$?

Tags: functions

I think I encountered this function from a research paper, but I cannot remember its title. Is there a specific name for the function

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{(c+e^{-x})}$$

where c is a constant?

Also, does it have something to do with the sigmoid function? I am planning to construct an activation function related to this one.

Thanks!

Comment: It's a "logistic curve".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called the [logistic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function). A [sigmoid function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function) is something similar.

You can change your function
$$
{1\over c+e^{-x}}
$$
into the format given at the article by altering the values of $x_0$ and $L$ in the Wikipedia example, specifically set $L=1/c$ and $x_0=-\log c$ then
$$
{1\over c+e^{-x}}={1/c
\over
1+e^{-x-\log c}
}
=
{L\over1+e^{-(x-x_0)}}
$$

[This search site](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24f(x)%3D1%2F(c%2Be%5E%7B-x%7D)%24&p=1) might be useful next time.